# Figuring out what this Trim() function is doing?

Tags: informix, datastage

I have a constraint on a transformer with this:

```
Trim(CollectFrom.collect_from,"-","A")<=TheDate
```

Here is what collect_from looks like:

```
'2017-02-27'
```

And here is what TheDate looks like:

```
'20170227'
```

I am unsure exactly how this Trim() function works. My first guess is that it is giving it the same format as 'TheDate' however I don't understand the "A" argument. Could somebody explain it?

Answer (score 3):

The manual page for [TRIM()](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_1556.htm) says that shouldn't work.

When I try to run what you show, I get errors:

```
SQL[2405]: select trim('2017-02-01', '-', 'A') from dual;
SQL -674: Routine (trim) can not be resolved. 
SQLSTATE: IX000 at /dev/stdin:1
SQL[2406]: select trim('2017-02-01', '-') from dual;
SQL -674: Routine (trim) can not be resolved. 
SQLSTATE: IX000 at /dev/stdin:2
```

The manual says you need `TRIM({BOTH|LEADING|TRAILING} [char] FROM source)`:

```
SQL[2407]: select trim(both '-' from '2017-02-12') from dual;
2017-02-12
SQL[2408]: select trim(both '-' from '2017-02-12-') from dual;
2017-02-12
SQL[2409]: select trim(both '-' from '-2017-02-12-') from dual;
2017-02-12
SQL[2410]:
```

(The SQL command interpreter used is my [SQLCMD](http://members.iiug.org/software/index_ESQLC.html).)

There's a chance that someone has defined a TRIM function that takes three arguments — that's not detectable from here.   You'd have to look in the system catalog of your database to find that.

OTOH, that doesn't seem to be allowed, either:

```
SQL[2411]: create function trim(a varchar(10), b varchar(20), c varchar(30)) returning varchar(64);
return trim(leading from a) || ' ' || trim(both from b) || ' ' || trim(trailing from c);
end function;
SQL -9710: Overloading of built-in functions is not allowed.
SQLSTATE: IX000 at /dev/stdin:8
SQL[2412]:
```

Answer (score 2):

Informix 11.50 has build in `trim()` function: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_11.50.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_1556.htm But it looks little different from `trim()` in your question, so I think you use `trim()` function build by some user.

Normally `trim()` takes care only at chars at beginning or at end of the string, but in your example `trim()` had to remove `-` chars that are in the middle of the string. I guess that last argument `A` tells `trim()` to remove all such characters from source string.

To find out what `trim()` function really do you must find it source. You can do it with some GUI database tools like SQirreL SQL Client (it uses JDBC), you can do it with `dbschema` Informix utility or with my Python/Jython program that uses ODBC/JDBC: https://code.activestate.com/recipes/576621-dump-informix-schema-to-text

It would be helpful to tell us what version of Informix you use.

Answer (score 0):

Trim(CollectFrom.collect_from,"-","A")

Here **A** means to **Remove all the occurrences** of '-' from the input string CollectFrom.collect_from . Hence You are getting '20170227' . Here is the document which would give further more information on Trim function.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSZJPZ_11.5.0/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.ds.parjob.dev.doc/topics/r_deeref_String_Functions.html